# Seeking manual/doc on the Nest thermostat REST api on how to change the schedule

Tags: nest-api

I can not find any manual on the Nest thermostat REST api. I see examples of changing the temperature but need to know how to change the schedule. Please lead me to documentation to do this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can find all the documentation on developer.nest.com, however you cannot edit the schedule via the API.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Our mobile app (My Energy Tool) for Wiser thermostats supports changing the thermostat schedule. Is there a way I can change the schedule for a Nest thermostat, or is that locked out so developer apps can not do?

Comment: Essentially, yeah. The manual schedule and the learning schedule are set on the nest side only. You could have the user disable both schedules on nest thermostat and then you could build your own schedule system to change setpoints, but that only works if the thermostat is set to Home mode. I wouldn't recommend doing that though :p